# Usar ID na URL para Wordpress SEO

Tags: seo

Estou com uma dúvida cruel se devo ou não usar o post_id na URL.

Atualmente estou usando :

/%category%/%postname%-%post_id%.html

será que vale a pena retirar esse post_id ou criar com um barra separando o id do nome do post?

/%category%/%postname%/%post_id%.html

Answer (score 0):

Olhando somente para SEO, acredito que você deixando sua URL sem números, deixando o mais "amigável" possível, assim fica de melhor leitura ao usuário e aos robots das Search Engines.

Porém considerando que você já possui uma URL, em um ambiente em produção, vale a pena avaliar o impacto disto, se for pouco, acredito que seria válido remover o "post_id" da url como um todo.

EX: /%category%/%postname%.html

Comment: No meu caso estou criando um portal atualmente tenho 10 mil links. Não sei se com o tempo quando tiver mais posts vai ficar lento o Wordpress se eu remover o post_id por isso bateu a dúvida.